# fxflex how to get the div size depending on content

Tags: flexbox

I want to do div, it has 2 different items, first one, can be shorter or longer depending on data. The second one is fixed height and it position starts when the first one ends.

The first have scroll if needed.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>
  <!-- other items -->

   <div fxFlex fxLayout="column">

    <div fxFlex class="scroll">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
          {{item}}
       </ng-container>
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="15%">
        <button> button </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With this code what I get is the second div is always at bottom.

how can I do the first div have the height it needs depending on its content?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this: `[fxFlex]='height'`, where 'height' its a variable in your .ts file, you can change this height depending on the data you get.

For example, if you want that every item had height = 50px, you can make

```
height = items[lenght] * 50;
height = height + 'px';
```

Later, if you want that div don't get higher than 300px, you can add an additional step:

```
height = items[lenght] * 50;
if (height > 300) height = 300;
height = height + 'px';
```

I hope this can help you